# AngularJS - success/failure/info messages

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add messages module to angular. This will show message after actions like add new item, update, delete etc.

Messages like:
* "succefully updated user"
* "succefully removed user"
* "can't delete user - your session is expired"
etc.

User should can hide every message after read.

Can I find some good, recommended plugin for it? If not, how should I do it?

In actions like adding, deleting, updating etc. this can be done automaticaly. I think.

Comment: http://ngmodules.org/modules/message-center very easy to use/customise. Good luck

Comment: You can grab message from your response and put at ui-view or partial view, also use bootstrap for nice html. Angular has ngMessages if you prefer

Comment: REST api should return message? For example if I send PUT request to ex.com/users/1 and get status code 200 and content like {message: "user succefully added"}. I'm not sure it's good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of [ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages) ? It looks like exactly what you need, although it doesn't provides templates.